# How make paginate(LARAVEL) in query SQL

Tags: laravel

I have the query:

```
 $estadolocacaoname = "naolocado";
 $consulta = DB::select("SELECT locacao.estadolocacao, automovel.marca, automovel.modelo 
                        FROM locacao 
                        INNER JOIN automovel 
                        ON locacao.id = automovel.id 
                        where locacao.estadolocacao = ? ",[$estadolocacaoname]);
```

How make paginate of LARAVEL?

Comment: Did you define eloquent models?

Comment: i Don't use eloquent, only query builder, eloquent is the dificult for me. I like the running query sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel's pagination is a breeze when you use the query builder:

```
DB::table('locacao')
  ->join('automovel', 'locacao.id', '=', 'automovel.id')
  ->select('locacao.estadolocacao', 'automovel.marca', 'automovel.modelo')
  ->where('locacao.estadolocacao', '=', $estadolocacaoname)
  ->paginate(15);
```